# Proving/disproving a statement regarding an anti-hermitian matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

I'm feeling like this is a disproof situation yet I cant come up with a working counter-example to the statement:

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an anti-hermitian matrix (such that $A=-A^*$ then for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$ : $Rank(A-\alpha I)=n$

I'm aware that because $A$ is anti-hermitian, than all eigenvalues are pure imaginary.

What bothers me is the thought that $(A-\alpha I)$ could have a column $j$ where $a_{j,j}=0$ which then drops the rank of the matrix, in the case where $\alpha = a_{j,j}$ which is a possible(?) situation.

Not sure where to take it from here, any tips/assistance could be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Diagonal entries of any anti-Hermitian matrix are purely imaginary, while diagonal entries of $\alpha I$ have nonzero real part (as they are $\alpha$). So $a_{j,j}=0$ is not possible. But all this is a bit beside the point; having $\operatorname{rank}(A-\alpha I)<n$ would mean $\det(A-\alpha I)=0$ and so $\alpha$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$, which it is not.

Comment: I understand.
So because none of the diagonal entries of $A$ is $0$ for $(A-\alpha I)$, the rank stays the same.

thanks!